$P(X_1 < X_2 < \text{others})$ for non-identically distributed independent random variables $X_1,\cdots, X_n$.
Let $X_1,\cdots X_n$ be independent normal random variables with means $\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n$ and unit variances. Then by definition, we have
$$P(X_1 < X_2 < \text{others})=$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x_1}^{\infty}\int_{x_2}^{\infty} \sum_{\substack{\sigma \in S_n \\ \sigma(1)=1\\ \sigma(2)=2}}\int_{x_{\sigma(3)}}^{\infty}\int_{x_{\sigma(4)}}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{x_{\sigma(n-2)}}^{\infty}\int_{x_{\sigma(n-1)}}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i-\theta_i)\,dx_{\sigma(n)}\,dx_{\sigma(n-1)}\cdots \,dx_{\sigma(4)}\,dx_{\sigma(3)}\,dx_2\,dx_1$$
which is an extremely complicated sum of $(n-2)!$ $n$-dimensional integrals.
I am trying to derive a simpler formula but I am not sure if my proof is correct:
$$P(X_1 < X_2 < \text{others})=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x_1}^{\infty}P(\text{$X_2$ is the smallest other than $X_1$}|X_2=x_2)\phi(x_2-\theta_2)\phi(x_1-\theta_1)\,dx_2\,dx_1$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x_1}^{\infty}P(X_3>X_2, \cdots, X_n>X_2|X_2=x_2)\phi(x_2-\theta_2)\phi(x_1-\theta_1)\,dx_2\,dx_1$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x_1}^{\infty}P(X_3>x_2, \cdots, X_n>x_2|X_2=x_2)\phi(x_2-\theta_2)\phi(x_1-\theta_1)\,dx_2\,dx_1$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x_1}^{\infty}P(X_3>x_2)\cdots P(X_n>x_2)\phi(x_2-\theta_2)\phi(x_1-\theta_1)\,dx_2\,dx_1 \ \text{by independence}$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x_1}^{\infty}\prod_{i\not=1,2}(1-\Phi(x_2-\theta_i))\phi(x_2-\theta_2)\phi(x_1-\theta_1)\,dx_2\,dx_1$$
Thank you so much in advance.

Querry.  Does $X_1<X_2<\textbf{others}$ mean $X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4\ldots<X_n$ or simply $X_1<X_2<\min{X_3,X_4,...,X_n}$ ?

Hi @GrahamKemp, it means $X_1<X_2<\cdots <\min {X_3,\cdots, X_n}$.

Your formula is too complicated. There should be no need of solving double integrals.
Let $A$ be the event that $X_1$ is smallest amongst $X_1, \ldots, X_n$; $B$ be the event that $X_2$ is the smallest amongst $X_2, \ldots, X_n$; $C$ be your event that $X_1 < X_2 < \text{others}$. We make two observations. Firstly, we have that $C = A \cap B$. Secondly, the event $A^c \cap B$ means $X_2$ is the smallest amaongst $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.
Therefore :
\begin{equation*}
P(C) = P(A \cap B) = P(B) - P(A^c \cap B)
\end{equation*}
It suffices to calculate $P(B)$ and $P(A^c \cap B)$. But they are standard order statistics. You can find answers say from https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/order_stats.pdf . When it is normal distribution, closed forms are definitely available and can be quickly computed.

We have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<\text{other})&=\mathbb{P}(\{X_1<X_2\}\cap \{X_2<X_3 \}\cap \{X_2<X_4 \}\cap...\cap  \{X_2<X_n \})\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\{X_1-X_2<0\}\cap \bigcap_{i=3}^n\{X_i-X_2>0 \})\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Denote $Y_1= X_1-X_2$ and for $i = 2,...,n-1$: $Y_i = X_{n+1}-X_2$ then
$$\cases{
Y_1 \sim\mathcal{N}(\theta_1-\theta_2,2)\\
Y_i \sim\mathcal{N}(\theta_{i+1}-\theta_2,2)\hspace{1cm}\forall i=2,..,(n-1)\\}$$
The vector $(Y_1,..,Y_{n-1})$ follows the multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}_{n-1}(\Theta,\Sigma)$ where
$$\cases{\Theta_i = \cases{\theta_{1}-\theta_2&for $i=1$\\\theta_{i+1}-\theta_2&for $i=2,...,n-1$}\\
\Sigma_{ij}=Cov(Y_i,Y_j) \hspace{0.5cm}\text{that is easy to compute} }$$
Then, from $(1)$, we have the closed form expression of $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<\text{other})$:
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<\text{other}) = \Phi_{n-1}\left( \pmatrix{0\\-\infty\\...\\-\infty}, \pmatrix{\infty\\0\\...\\0};\Theta,\Sigma \right)} \tag{2}$$
The expression $(2)$ is in fact an integral of $(n-1)$ dimension and can be numerically computed by fast algorithms such that (Genz, 1992) which is widely implemented in Matlab, Python,..
